# pexpect timed out before script ends

Tags: pexpect

I am using pexpect to connect to a remote server using ssh.

The following code works but I have to use time.sleep to make a delay.

Especially when I am sending a command to run a script on the remote server.

The script will take up to a minute to run and if I don't use a 60 seconds delay, then the script will end prematurely.

The same issue when I am using sftp to download a file. If the file is large, then it download partially.

Is there a way to control without using a delay?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pexpect
import time
from subprocess import call

siteip = "131.235.111.111"
ssh_new_conn = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
password = 'xxxxx'

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@' + siteip)
time.sleep(1)
child.expect('admin@.* password:')
child.sendline('xxxxx')
time.sleep(2)
child.expect('admin@.*')
print('ssh to abcd - takes 60 seconds')
child.sendline('backuplog\r')
time.sleep(50)
child.sendline('pwd')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many pexpect functions take an optional `timeout=` keyword, and the one you give in `spawn()` sets the default. Eg

```
child.expect('admin@',timeout=70)
```

You can use the value `None` to never timeout.

Comment: It seems the sendline doesn't accept the timeout argument
child.sendline('backuplog\r', timeout=None)

Comment: That is because sendline is unlikely to be delayed, so no timeout is provided. There is a lot of buffering of output for networks in the kernel, so sendline usually returns immediately, unless you are repeatedly writing large amounts of data.

Comment: What actually I want is not to delay with the sendline. I want to have a delay after the sendline is sent. I can have a manual delay but the problem is than I don't know how long the transfer file is going to take. If I don't have a delay, then the transfer file will not be completed

Comment: Typically, you can use `.expect()` with a long timeout and a pattern to look for some indication that the backuplog command has finished, such as the prompt from the remote for the next command. Or you can try sending ahead of time a command that makes the remote close the connection, perhaps `exit` or `logout`, and then you can use `child.wait()` which returns only when the connection is closed.

Comment: As you can see on the code above, I have a "pwd" command after "backuplog" command. The "pwd" command has a predictable output so I have "child.expect(/home*.) after that line which is not shown on the code above). Still, if I don't use delay, the "backuplog" command which supposed to download a tar file, exit prematurely.